# How can I use 'BEFORE DELETE' trigger with conditions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

colleagues! I created 'product' table with the next query:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
id serial not null,
product_name text not null,
description varchar(50),
delivery_date timestamp,
warehouse jsonb
)
```

And I'm trying to use trigger before delete with the sort by list:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION product_delete_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (OLD.product_name IN ('Milk','Egg','Cheese'))
        THEN 
        DELETE FROM product WHERE product_name = OLD.product_name;
    ELSE
         RAISE EXCEPTION
    'Value out of list.  Fix the product_delete_trigger() function!';
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delete_product_trigger
  BEFORE DELETE ON product
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE product_delete_trigger();
```

How I got it I need to use 'OLD' special parameter , but If I when I use it, I have an issue:

```
ERROR: ERROR: Stack depth limit exceeded
HINT: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (the current value is 2048 KB), first making sure that the OS provides sufficient stack size.
```

Is it possible to do this by this query?

```
DELETE FROM product where product_name = 'Cheese';
```

Comment: If you want the delete to proceed, just don't block it.

Comment: But How do I block it? I need to delete that row where product_name that is specified from query also in the list of value and need to do it before delete from trigger function. I'll do the same from inherit partition after.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to manually delete the same row that was being deleted in the first place, which then causes an infinite loop because it too fires the trigger.  So don't do that.  To allow the deletion to proceed, just do what the docs say, `RETURN OLD`.

Comment: Would you have several rows in table `product` with the same `product_name` value and that you would want to delete as a block when one of the rows is deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in running `DELETE` in your `BEFORE` trigger – that happens anyway if you let the database have its course.  So all you have to do is throw an error if you are unhappy with the proceedings:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION product_delete_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF ((OLD.product_name IN ('Milk','Egg','Cheese')) IS NOT TRUE)
    THEN 
         RAISE EXCEPTION
         'Value out of list.  Fix the product_delete_trigger() function!';
    END IF;
    /* proceed with the DELETE */
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```